# global variable python, doesn't run

Tags: python

I try to run this code in python 3.6

```
def Arrange(num):
    global sec
    sec=0
def Digit(nmb):
    return nmb%10
def WithoutTheLastDigit(nmb2):
    return nmb2//10
def IsEven(even):
    if even%2==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def AddDigit(number,dig):
    number=number*10+dig
while num>0:
    Digit(num)
    if IsEven(Digit(num))==True:
        sec=sec+AddDigit(sec,Digit(num))
    WithoutTheLastDigit(num)
print(sec)
```

and it shows this error:

> >>> Arrange(500)
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           Arrange(500)
>         File "C:\Users\Yair\Desktop\hw3.py", line 56, in Arrange
>           sec=sec+AddDigit(sec,Digit(num))
>       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: What does the `AddDigit` function **`return`**?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The error may have been caused by wrong indentation. We need to see what you actually had in your program.

Comment: Your posted code fails to compile on line 2, AddDigit returns `None` by definition, and you haven't tried to trace the values involved.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the function `AddDigit()` returns `None`:

```
def AddDigit(number,dig):
    number=number*10+dig
    # this return None by default. mussing `return number`

while num>0:
    Digit(num)
    if IsEven(Digit(num))==True:
        sec=sec+AddDigit(sec,Digit(num))  # This is 0 + None
    WithoutTheLastDigit(num)
```

Note that you code can be simplify greatly with a few things. I didn't change the logic, so you might have some errors here.

```
def Digit(number):
    return number % 10

def WithoutTheLastDigit(number):
    return number // 10

def IsEven(number):
    return number % 2 == 0:

def AddDigit(number, digit):
    return number*10 + digit

while number > 0:
    digit = Digit(number)
    if IsEven(digit):
        sec += AddDigit(sec, digit)

print(sec)
```